# idangerous swiper work slow on android

Tags: javascript, android, swiper.js

```
var swiper_category_slider = new Swiper('.category-slider', {
            pagination: '.swiper-pagination',
            paginationClickable: true,
            slidesPerView: 5,
            spaceBetween: 20,
            breakpoints: {
                1024: {
                    slidesPerView: 6,
                    spaceBetween: 20
                },
                768: {
                    slidesPerView: 5,
                    spaceBetween: 10
                },
                640: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                    spaceBetween: 7
                },
                320: {
                    slidesPerView: 2,
                    spaceBetween: 7
                }
            }
        });
```

I don't know why when the slider is loading it makes a little effect and on android works sooo slow, I read the documentation but nothing works for my problem.. Any solution?